# Remove Last instance of a character and rest of a string

Tags: python, regex

If I have a string as follows:

`foo_bar_one_two_three`

Is there a clean way, with RegEx, to return: `foo_bar_one_two`?

I know I can use split, pop and join for this, but I'm looking for a cleaner solution.

Comment: I don't know Python, but in sed it's `s/_[^_]*$//`.

Comment: You can do as @Beta said with `re` module: `re.sub(r'_[^_]*$', '', 'foo_bar_one_two_three')`. But I would recommend using @Tadeck answer instead.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

```py
result = my_string.rsplit('_', 1)[0]
```

Which behaves like this:

```py
>>> my_string = 'foo_bar_one_two_three'
>>> print(my_string.rsplit('_', 1)[0])
foo_bar_one_two
```

See in the documentation entry for [`str.rsplit([sep[, maxsplit]])`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.rsplit).

Answer (score 3):

One way is to use `rfind` to get the index of the last `_` character and then slice the string to extract the characters up to that point:

```
>>> s = "foo_bar_one_two_three"
>>> idx = s.rfind("_")
>>> if idx >= 0:
...     s = s[:idx]
...
>>> print s
foo_bar_one_two
```

You need to check that the `rfind` call returns something greater than -1 before using it to get the substring otherwise it'll strip off the last character.

If you *must* use regular expressions (and I tend to prefer non-regex solutions for simple cases like this), you can do it thus:

```
>>> import re
>>> s = "foo_bar_one_two_three"
>>> re.sub('_[^_]*$','',s)
'foo_bar_one_two'
```

Answer (score 3):

Similar the the `rsplit` solution, `rpartition` will also work:

```
result = my_string.rpartition("_")[0]
```

You'll need to watch out for the case where the separator character is not found. In that case the original string will be in index 2, not 0.

doc string:

> rpartition(...)
>
> S.rpartition(sep) -> (head, sep, tail)
>
> Search for the separator sep in S, starting at the end of S, and return
>      the part before it, the separator itself, and the part after it.  If the
>      separator is not found, return two empty strings and S.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a **generic function** to remove everything after the last occurrence of any specified string. For extra credit, it also supports removing everything after the nth last occurrence.

```
def removeEverythingAfterLast (needle, haystack, n=1):
    while n > 0:
        idx = haystack.rfind(needle)
        if idx >= 0:
            haystack = haystack[:idx]
            n -= 1
        else:
            break
    return haystack
```

In your case, to remove everything after the last '_', you would simply call it like this:

```
updatedString = removeEverythingAfterLast('_', yourString)
```

If you wanted to remove everything after the 2nd last '_', you would call it like this:

```
updatedString = removeEverythingAfterLast('_', yourString, 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

I know is python, and my answer may be a little bit wrong in syntax, but in java you would do:

```
String a = "foo_bar_one_two_three";
String[] b = a.split("_");
String c = "";
for(int i=0; i<b.length-1; a++){
    c += b[i];
    if(i != b.length-2){
        c += "_";
    }
}
//and at this point, c is "foo_bar_one_two"
```

Hope in python `split` function works same way. :)

EDIT:

Using the limit part of the function you can do:

```
String a = "foo_bar_one_two_three";
String[] b = a.split("_",StringUtils.countMatches(a,"_"));
//and at this point, b is the array = [foo,bar,one,two]
```

Comment: Python is more concise. What you have done would be basically something like `'_'.join(a.split('_')[:-1])`. I think the steps you take are exactly the same as are executed in almost 30-chars long example.